# How to translate cURL in a C# Webrequest?

Tags: c#, .net, curl

Good morning all,
I have been looking for an answer to my question for a while but I haven't found anything.
I need to make a REST call to a Webapi, this is the code that I use with cURL:

```
curl -X POST --include 'https://animetrics.p.mashape.com/detect?api_key=sample' \
  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: sample' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d 'selector=FACE, EYES, FULL' \
  -d 'url=http://example.com/some_image.jpg'
```

I have been able to write the following piece of code in C#:

```
public string MakeRequest(string parameters)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint);

        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;
        request.Headers["X-Mashape-Key"] = "sample";
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        PostData += "selector=FACE&";
        PostData += "url=" +HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.sample.it/sample.jpg");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            var bytes= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // grab the response
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

            return responseValue;
        }
    }
```

But as a response I always get a json object that inside says:

```
"{\"errors\":{\"url\":\"url or image field required\"}}"
```

Could someone please give me some help?
Thank you

**UPDATE:**
Problem solved I was just missing a final d in the Content-Type field.
Thank you to all!

Comment: Where are `PostData`  and `ContentType` defined?

Comment: @Eris they are defined in the class that I have created as parameters. The piece of code that i have posted is a method of the class. thank you

Comment: You should [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) the values of POST parameters, like this: `PostData+="url="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://example.com/some_image.jpg");` If this doesn't work, use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see exact requests that are made with cUrl and your code and find the differences.

Comment: @qbik I have changed the code in the way you said but it's still not working (still same json object returned with "url missing").Thank you anyway

Comment: @qbik Problem solved I was just missing a final d in the Content-Type field.
Thank you to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Problem solved I was just missing a final d in the Content-Type field and the error was not signaled from the debugger. Thank you to all!
Michele